# Transpose in Google BigQuery/Excel

Tags: sql, excel, google-bigquery, pivot-table

I have a question regarding data transport in BQ (or actually export and do it in Excel). I am trying to get this result (Sorry I am new and not sure how to separate 2 columns, variant1 and variant2 should be 2 columns) :

| ClientID | Date | Variant1. Variant2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 12/2 | 123. 456 |

My current query will give this output:

| ClientID | Date | Variant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 12/1 | 123 |
| AB | 12/2 | 456 |

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  case when (hits.ecommerceAction.action_type = '3') then date end date, [enter image description here][1]
  clientId AS client_id,
  page.pagepath as pagepath,
  product.productVariant as variant,
FROM
  `xxxx.ga_sessions_`,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits, unnest(hits.product) as product
```

Is there anyway that I can use to achieve the transpose step? My current output is more like a master data, all the product related information is under one column. Appreciate if you can share any thoughts!

Comment: are you sure presented query actually produces any result? if so, can you please share sample of output, so we can use it as a starting point and further help you

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Hi, I just updated the screenshot of output here as a reference, thanks!

Comment: image is something hard to use - can you please copy paste result as a text so we can play with it. also not clear what is expected result - please add it into your question too

Comment: Hi, sorry I am super new and am not sure how to separate 2 columns, variant1 and variant2 should be 2 columns. I took your suggestion and updated tables, hope it's better! @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: see my answer along with comment below it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select ClientID, Variant, Pagepath,
    max(Date) over win Date,
    row_number() over (win order by Date) pos
  from your_current_output
  window win as (partition by ClientID)
)
pivot (any_value(Variant) as Variant, any_value(Pagepath) as Pagepath for pos in (1,2,3))
```

if to apply to sample in your question

```
with your_current_output as (
  select '12/1' Date, 123 ClientID, 'abc' Variant, 'fis.com' Pagepath union all
  select '12/2', 123, 'efg', 'fere.com'
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Hey, you are changing your question too frequently. Note: I provided answer to that version of your question and respective data samples that I saw about 10 min ago.

Comment: Hi this worked perfectly! Good to learn how to make transpose command in Big Query, was so used to the proc transpose in SAS. Thank you for the knowledge, accepted the answer.